# BPP is closed to Symmetric difference?

Tags: complexity-theory

How can I prove that BPP is close to Symmetric difference?
I tried to find proof online but couldn't.
Can anyone please provide a quick explanation (if it's trivial and I just can't see it) or a link to proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A, B \in BPP$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ (resp. $\mathcal{B}$) be an algorithm for $A$ (resp. $B$) with a probability of error of at most $\frac{1}{3}$.

Given $x$ the following algorithm decides whether $x \in A \Delta B$ with a probability of error of at most $\frac{1}{3}$:

- Perform nine independent executions of $\mathcal{A}(x)$.
- Perform nine independent executions of $\mathcal{B}(x)$.
- If the majority of the executions of $\mathcal{A}(x)$ had a different outcome (i.e., accept or reject) than the majority of the executions of $\mathcal{B}(x)$ then accept. Otherwise reject.

The probability that the majority outcome among of the executions of $\mathcal{A}(x)$ (resp.  $\mathcal{B}(x)$) does not match whether $x \in A$ (resp. $x \in B$) is at most the probability that at least $5$ out of the $9$ executions fail. I.e., it is at most:
$$
\sum_{i=5}^9 \binom{9}{i} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^i  \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{9-i} = \frac{2851}{19683} < \frac{1}{6}.
$$

Using the union bound, the probability that *at least one* of the majority outcomes of $\mathcal{A}(x)$ and $\mathcal{B}(x)$ is incorrect is less than $2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$. Whenever both the majority outcomes are correct, the result of the above algorithm is also correct.